# Spread operator throwing unexpected token error in Alexa

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Spread operator throwing an unexpected token error inside an alexa skill

Adding babel, es-lint packages to package.json

My data is of the following format:

```
[ { id: 18460084, payload: { data: [Object], type: 'Data' } } ]
```

I tried the following:

```
payload.data.slots.map(slot => ({...slot.productData, sku: slot.sku, slotId: slot.slotId}))
```

A sample slot object:

```
{ slots:
   [ { sku: '142',
       productData: { publish_time: '2019-09-02T05:45:19',
                      description: 'blah blah',
                      url: '/product/111',
                    }
       slotId: 'l4SobG9jYXRp'}
    ] 
}
```

But I keep getting the 'unpexpected token' error inside Alexa..

Expected: an array of json objects 
actual result: unexpected token error.

Comment: There is no spread operator, there is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: how does this look like: ...slot.productData

Comment: added a sample feed..

Comment: Which version of Node are you using? Maybe you need the `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` plugin for Babel - https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread

Answer (score 1):

I had to extract each element of the json array separately. I could not make spread operator work inside alexa even though my node was the latest version..